# .htaccess mod_write suppress rewrite on a directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to suppress mod_write on a directory. Currently when I go to `http://example.com/directory/file.php`, it routes me to `http://example.com/file.php`. I want it to simply serve up the `file.php` that is there. I've tried doing

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/directory/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^directory/*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

neither seems to work. Is there anything else I can try?

Here is the full file...

```
#php_value safe_mode off
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
  ModPagespeed off
</IfModule>

# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

##Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^image/data/(.*)$ /image/catalog/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
############First Mod 12/16 Only One Address Per Site#########

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pagespeed

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A0
</IfModule>
# Set up caching on media files for 5 weeks
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
ExpiresDefault A3024000
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

# Set up caching on media files for 5 weeks
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault A3024000
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

# Set up 1 day caching on commonly updated files
<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html|js|css)$">
ExpiresDefault A604800
Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# Force no caching for dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl|htm)$">
ExpiresActive Off
Header set Cache-Control "private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript image/x-icon
    <filesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php|ico)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesMatch> </ifModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>


<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                  "application/javascript" \
                                  "application/json" \
                                  "application/ld+json" \
                                  "application/manifest+json" \
                                  "application/rdf+xml" \
                                  "application/rss+xml" \
                                  "application/schema+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                  "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                  "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                  "application/x-javascript" \
                                  "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                  "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                  "application/xml" \
                                  "font/eot" \
                                  "font/opentype" \
                                  "image/bmp" \
                                  "image/svg+xml" \
                                  "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                  "image/x-icon" \
                                  "text/cache-manifest" \
                                  "text/css" \
                                  "text/html" \
                                  "text/javascript" \
                                  "text/plain" \
                                  "text/vcard" \
                                  "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                  "text/vtt" \
                                  "text/x-component" \
                                  "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                  "text/xml"

</IfModule>
```

Comment: 1. `REQUEST_URI` contains front slash, so `%{REQUEST_URI} !^directory/*$` never matches. 2. the `RewriteBase /` is sensitive to the htaccess path, so it need to be clarified. 3. and about rewritecond w/o following rewriterule read the below.

Comment: "when I go to `/directory/file.php`, it routes me to `/file.php`" - What do you mean exactly by this? Are you externally redirected (ie. the URL changes)? Or do you see the content from the file in the document root instead? There is nothing in your `.htaccess` file that appears to do this? A request for `/directory/file.php` would be internally routed to `/index.php?_route_=directory/file.php` (but only if that file did not exist) - at least according to the directives you have posted. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? Any directives in the server config?

Comment: @w3dk, the get 404 error (file cannot be found) but the URL changes to from /directory/file.php to /file.php. But the page that is served is page not found

Comment: Can you confirm that this is a 3xx redirect (check the network traffic in the browser). What type of redirect? 301, 302?

Comment: It says 302 redirect.

Comment: There would seem to be "something else" going on here (possibly in the PHP code / OpenCart?). There is nothing in the code you have posted that would trigger such a redirect. (?!)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead of `REQUEST_FILENAME`:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
```

I found the same problem on one of my sites.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to suppress mod_write on a directory.

To do this, you can create a `.htaccess` file in that directory and simply enable the rewrite engine:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default, so this completely overrides the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file.

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/directory/.*$ [NC]
> RewriteRule . - [L]
> ```

This should also work, providing it was placed at the start of your `.htaccess` file. Incidentally, a pattern like `^/directory/.*$` is the same as simply, `^/directory/`. If you are on Apache 2.4+ then you can use the `END` flag instead of `L`.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pagespeed
> ```

This appears to be a *stray* condition at end of your mod_rewrite rules!? This will cause problems if you include any mod_rewrite directives after it (as in *anywhere* in the file).

Comment: I commented out `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pagespeed` and that didn't help. I also tried creating a new `.htaccess` file in the directory with just `RewriteEngine On`... also did not work.....  =**************( I'm getting really desperate..... thank you for your help!